# Eclipse terminal / shell output encoding

Tags: eclipse, configuration

I'm using Eclipse under Windows 7, but I need Bash to get done any serious work so I have Cygwin installed. I'm running Bash in [mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) alongside Eclipse, but using bash_completion slows it down and it's "yet another window open" in my work environment, so it's cumbersome to use.

Lately however I've found out that I can start an SSH session inside Eclipse, hence I've set up an SSH server under Cygwin and I'm connecting to it from Eclipse.

It's working very well... except the character encoding sucks and I can't seem to be configure it.

By *sucks* I mean: in mintty non-ASCII characters are displayed correctly, in the SSH session in Eclipse they do not, so it is an encoding issue inside Eclipse.

Any idea how can I configure this?

I've tried the following: set every possible encoding options in Eclipse to UTF-8; in eclipse.ini I've passed the following JVM arguments to Eclipse.

```
-vmargs
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Nothing changed.

Comment: Regarding bash-completion, just uninstall it or remove its startup script from `/etc/profile.d`. It provides advanced completion features for things like command options or version control repositories, but basic completion of commands, paths, user names and such like is provided by bash itself.

Comment: I use git/svn from the command-line so it's good to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Remote System Explorer you can create connections in the Remote System Details view.  If you look at the properties of the connection, the Host tab allows you to set the default encoding used by that connection.

[image: Properties dialog with "Default encoding" at the bottom]

Comment: And it works! I never would have thought that I can create SSH terminal views from the remote explorer thingy, I've always used `Alt+Shift+Q -> Q -> Terminal -> Connect`. Thanks!

Comment: The link to the picture showing the answer is broken. Please, fix it if you can, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the "Remote" View (Window ↦ Show View ↦ Remote)
2. Right click on the Connection where you want to setup the charset
3. Choose "Properties" and open in the appearing Window the Part "More Options"
4. Choose your encoding.

You're done.